# How can I convert a ruby array of hashes into a single hash?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hash

If I start with an array of hashes like this:

```
[{"name"=>"apple", "value"=>"red"},
{"name"=>"banana", "value"=>"yellow"},
{"name"=>"grape", "value"=>"purple"}]
```

How can I turn it into this single hash:

```
{apple: "red", banana: "yellow", grape: "purple"}
```

Is there a quicker way than doing some sort of for loop?

Comment: converted it into a meaningful question using array of hashes into single hash

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
arr = [{"name"=>"apple",  "value"=>"red"},
       {"name"=>"banana", "value"=>"yellow"},
       {"name"=>"grape",  "value"=>"purple"}]

Hash[arr.map { |h| [h["name"].to_sym , h["value"]] }]
  #=> {:apple=>"red", :banana=>"yellow", :grape=>"purple"}
```

With Ruby 2.1+

```
arr.map { |h| [h["name"].to_sym , h["value"]] }.to_h
  #=> {:apple=>"red", :banana=>"yellow", :grape=>"purple"}
```

Comment: I was writing the same answer :P, I would just add symbolize_keys to match the exact result ;)

Comment: This is somewhat iffy because it relies on the ordering of the name/value keys; if one of the hashes were `{"value" =>"red", "name"=>"apple"}`, it would produce the wrong result.

Comment: @ChrisHeald That depends on what OP has. It is the OP's fault to have not made that clear. If the order is not guaranteed, the OP should have used an example that shows that.

Comment: Thanks @CarySwoveland.  In my case the order is always the same.  I should have noted that.

Answer (score 1):

### Create Hash from Splatted Array

If you don't actually need your keys to be symbols, this will work:

```
fruits = [{"name"=>"apple",  "value"=>"red"},
          {"name"=>"banana", "value"=>"yellow"},
          {"name"=>"grape",  "value"=>"purple"}]
Hash[*fruits.flat_map(&:values)]
#=> {"apple"=>"red", "banana"=>"yellow", "grape"=>"purple"}
```

### Indifferent Access

If you just want to *access* elements with symbols rather than strings, and you don't really care that the keys will actually be stored as strings, then you can require a small portion of the [ActiveSupport gem](https://rubygems.org/gems/activesupport) and use [HashWithIndifferentAccess](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/HashWithIndifferentAccess.html):

```
require 'active_support/core_ext/hash/indifferent_access'
fruits = [{"name"=>"apple",  "value"=>"red"},
          {"name"=>"banana", "value"=>"yellow"},
          {"name"=>"grape",  "value"=>"purple"}]
h = HashWithIndifferentAccess[*fruits.flat_map(&:values)]
h[:apple]
#=> "red"
```